# Survey writing best practices

Tags: surveys, inventory, questionnaire

My team at work is seeking a standard format for all survey questions meant to assess sentiment towards feature X (e.g., satisfaction, challenge level, enjoyability, navigability, etc.).

Imagining each is Likert scaled from 1 - K, do I ask:

1) How satisfied are you with X?
2) How dissatisfied or satisfied are you with X?
3) What do you think about X?

Concern with 1):  Is this a leading question?

Concern with 2):  Is this silly and unwieldy?  (i.e., imagine also: 'how difficult or easy was X' and 'Did you not understand or understand X' and 'Do you disagree or agree with this statement about X,' etc.)

Concern with 3): Is this too bland to gather nuanced information? (How do you get at deeper meanings such as 'X made me feel calm' or 'I always look forward to using X' or 'I often find myself playing 'just one more level' of X)

Thank you for your expertise!

SamUX

Answer (score 1):

It's good that you're thinking about the actual wording of your questions and issues such as 'leading questions' and so on.

I don't think one answer to your question is likely to apply to all the questions in your survey, so suggest you would be better served by doing some further reading on what makes a good survey. Below are some resources that may be useful:

- http://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/project_ideas/Soc_survey.shtml
- https://www.qualtrics.com/blog/good-survey-questions/
- https://www.qualtrics.com/blog/writing-survey-questions/
- http://www.socialresearchmethods.net/kb/survwrit.php
- http://blogs.constantcontact.com/how-to-write-survey/

Hopefully this will help. Good luck with your survey.

Comment: Thanks for responding!  Some of these links are helpful.  But to be clear, I don't have a problem understanding survey-writing in general (I'm actually quite practiced at it!).  The question I asked is the exact question I need the answer to.

Answer (score 0):

First of all when it comes with surveying don't ask in a negative wording.

like:

How dissatisfied or satisfied are you with X?

what suppose my answer would be!! (yes) I am dissatisfied or (no) I am not satisfied !! because some people don't really think and you should not (Don't let them Think) because when it comes to survey, always, negative answer is for bad things and positive answers is for good things and in such question I mention above. the unsatisfied people will answer positively which will be a little confused and sometimes its a tricky question. because if I answered a negative question negatively, that would be positive (negative negative is positive)

sometimes people do survey with negative questions to either the surveyor or to get results that aren't real.

for me I would like question (1) the most and after it comes (3) but question (3) it you let the user put his opinion in wording, I will advise you not to let the user put his/her opinion and never do that in a survey. because you may get answers like "I would like X but there is some things I hat in it" ... this answer will never gives you it he like X or not after all. But id the question (3) coves with a pre-made answers (multiple choice) that would be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your primary goal is to figure out priorities for future development, e.g. in corporate environment (as opposed to making the survey as easy to complete as possible with a 5-star system, e.g. for a game on mobile):

Then you need 4 pieces of information about each feature:

- *from logs, not from survey: what did the user do with the application*
- How important was *feature X* to complete your task today? 
   Not important at all - Little important - Somewhat important - Very important
- How easy was it to use *feature X*? 
   :] - :) - :( - :[
- Would you like to add any comments?

On desktop screen resolutions, the 3 questions easily fit next to each other, so you can have 1 row per feature with "columns" in the same format to make it faster to complete the survey if all features are displayed on 1 page (not separated with "Next" button).